# Spring MVC mvc:resources location attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Guys I have also problem with loading static resources.

I think I have everything properly set up. But I don't understand **location** attribute of **mvc:resources**. What is it for?

if I have my static resources under location VAADIN/themes/theme/... (in several subfolders, images, css, js) what should be the correct values for location and mapping attributes?

When I have following in configuration:

```
<mvc:resources location="/VAADIN/" mapping="/VAADIN/**"/>
```

it doesn't work. I suppose the following part of log is related:

```
17:15:02.897 [http-8080-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#6': no
 URL paths identified
```

I receive **HTTP Status 404** for e.g. http://127.0.0.1/VAADIN/themes/theme/css/style.css

Comment: so your app is deployed as ROOT?

Comment: yes app is deployed in tomcat. the static content is under **webapps\ROOT\VAADIN\...**

Comment: everything seems ok with the given information. Perhaps the problem lies somewhere else. `ResourceHttpRequestHandler#6` looks odd - do you really have 6 of those? perhaps more than one `mvc:annotation-driven` ?

Answer (score 5):

`location` is the location to the folder where the resources are placed. The [XSD docs](http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd) write:

> The resource location from which to serve static content, specified at a Spring Resource pattern.
>       Each location must point to a valid directory. Multiple locations may be specified as a comma-separated list,
>       and the locations will be checked for a given resource in the order specified. For example, a value of
>       "/, classpath:/META-INF/public-web-resources/" will allow resources to be served both from the web app
>       root and from any JAR on the classpath  that contains a /META-INF/public-web-resources/ directory,
>       with resources in the web app root taking precedence.

On the other hand, the `mapping` attribute is:

> The URL mapping pattern, within the current Servlet context, to use for serving resources from this handler, such as "/resources/**"

So `mapping` specifies under what uri will resources be accessible on the web, while `location` specifies where are these resources located on the disk.

Comment: @coffy *hi, I think everybody can read docs.* No they can't. Otherwise this site wouldn't exist :-) But seriously: I'd say top developers trying to solve your problems for free deserve more respect than that, don't they?

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd Hi, I didn't meant to disrespect anybody. But I don't see very helpful putting Java/xsd/whatever docs as answer. ;) Take it as criticism not as some kind of attack to developer. I am the one too :) And thanks for renewed answer @Bozho And it would be great if could elaborate my part of config file. thx

Comment: @coffy - usually the docs contain all the answers. But I agree often someone has to point them or summarize them

Comment: @coffy yes we are all developers here, but a) bozho is the [number 2 spring expert on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring/topusers) and he's seldom wrong b) Spring docs are huge. Finding the relevant part is sometimes tricky, so posting docs is a very valid part of answering Spring problems

Answer (score 1):

My Guess is that you're not referencing the location correctly.

- Is your VAADIN folder inside the
  WAR's top level directory (in which
  case `location="/VAADIN/"` is
  correct)
- or is it in WEB-INF/classes (in which
  case it must be
  `location="classpath:/VAADIN/"`) ?

Comment: or he has not deployed it as ROOT, but omits the context path.

Comment: yes, my VAADIN folder is inside the WAR's top level directory, and application is deployed as ROOT in tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have configured some handlermapping that kicks in before the resourcehttprequestresolver (or whatever it's called)
Check that you don't have an AbstractUrlHandlerMapping or any other handlermapping that stops the mapping chain with an order property.
Or configure the resource resolver with an order: <mvc:resources ... order="1" />

```
<!-- Maps all other request URLs to views -->
<bean id="viewMappings" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="defaultHandler">
        <!-- Selects view names to render based on the request URI: e.g. the "/Home" URL would map to the view named "Home" -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
    </property>
    <!-- This will prevent the mvc:resources to handle requests. Unless, of course, you specify an order in the mvc:resources order attribute
    <property name="order" value="3" /  Removing this will place this just after The ResourceHttpRequestHandler-->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

sets up a handler for serving static content. The mapping attribute
is set to /resources/**, which includes an Ant-style wildcard to indicate that the path
must begin with /resources, but may include any subpath thereof. The location attribute
indicates the location of the files to be served. As configured here, any requests
whose paths begin with /resources will be automatically served from the /resources
folder at the root of the application. Therefore, all of our images, stylesheets,
JavaScript, and other static content needs to be kept in the application’s /resources
folder.