# Simple way to map a route in Spring MVC to a different folder path

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, url-routing

In my filesystem I have a `webapp` directory which is my root for the web application and it has `js`, `css`, and `images`, subdirectories (among others).

However (for reasons I won't go into) my organization would like to have `/app/` prefix our resources.  Thus the tags in the HTML look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app/js/folder/file.js"></script>
```

Requesting `localhost:port/js/folder/file.js` works, and `localhost:port/app/js/folder/file.js` doesn't (as expected for now).

Is there a simple way to have Spring MVC know that when it sees /app/js/* to drop the /app/ and serve the file from `webapp/js/`?

Comment: why not just move your resouces to "webapp/app/js/blah blah" directory as requested by your organisation ?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear.  I cannot move things around in the filesystem (for other reasons) and they have /app/ prefix all requests to our web app which I cannot change as well.  This stuff is not up to me :(

Comment: oh, take a look at this then http://stackoverflow.com/q/5379054/106261

Comment: If you deploy to tomcat and deploy your war as app.war instead of ROOT.war I think you get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying following configuration in your dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

```
<mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/app/js/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/app/css/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/app/images/**"/>
```

Hope this is helpful to you.

Cheers.