# How to dispatch static html pages who are not in WEB_INF Folder from spring controller

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I want that from my spring controller we can render static html page which are in root-context folder of my application. Like: if person is my root context

> - /person
>
>   1. content- it contains mt static html pages.
>   2. js
>   3. css
>   4. WEB-INF

I was trying to create a custom view resolver, but i didn't get success.

Comment: Please show your web.xml.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379054/spring-mvc-mvcresources-location-attribute

Comment: <beans:bean class="com.person.person.web.utils.CustomViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/content/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean> Hi Boris i know that we can use <mvc:resources> tag but i want dispatch html which is not in WEB-INF from controller.