# I have added css folder directly in web content and i have mapped in spring.xml. But css is not loading

Tags: java, spring-mvc

`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">  

    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.homebanking" /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:resources location="/css/*" mapping="/css/*"/>
    <mvc:resources location="/js/*" mapping="/js/*"/> 


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
    </bean>

    <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homebanking" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.homebanking.model"/>       
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

`

I have mapped [css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CscNx.png) file in spring-servlet.xml file using mvc:resource tag. But css is not loading. i have placed css folder in web content

```
 <mvc:resources location="/css/*" mapping="/css/*"/>
<mvc:resources location="/js/*" mapping="/js/*"/>
```

please help me out.it was working fine before. but suddenly css not loading.

Comment: Can you show me your folder structure, and your xml files please

Comment: am unable to add pic of my folder structure

Comment: i have placed css folder directly under webcontent folder

Comment: i have added my spring .xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your are placed your css folder under webcontent the you need to specify your resources like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

then you can import your css file like this:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/youMain.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: i changed as u said .. now it is working ..thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to write link this `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`
 for more you can refer bellow stackoverflow link to get proper reference :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32157609/7801800 by AshOne