# JSP href resources not found in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My file structure is as follows;

```
webapp
  resources
    foo.css
  WEB-INF
    home.jsp
    mgr
      ha.jsp
```

File home.jsp has the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="resources/foo.css
```

File ha.jsp has the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../resources/foo.css
```

In Spring I have the following statement in my extension of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

Spring is happy and both JSP files render properly. But both JSP files cause errors with the Eclipse JSP editor because the editor cannot resolve the file locations. To fix the errors with the JSP editor I would have to code file home.jsp like

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../../resources/foo.css
```

And code ha.jsp like

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../../resources/foo.css
```

But this causes the web page to fail because Spring cannot resolve the files. So I tried coding in Spring the following:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/","../../resources/");
```

This doesn't fix Spring but at least the JSP editor is happy. So how would I get out of the conflict and make both Spring and the JSP editor happy?

I read many possible explanations with this one being the best. [Spring MVC mvc:resources location attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379054/spring-mvc-mvcresources-location-attribute/5379083#5379083)
But I still could not get the problem resolved. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add foo.css file in your home.jsp like                                          `<link href="<c:url value="/resources/foo.css" />" rel="stylesheet">`      and don't forget to add                                                                    `<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

Comment: Thanks. That worked just fine.

Comment: One thing though, this change affected relative url's in my CSS files. I am correcting them now. Again, the tag lib change did correct my original problem.